# Question about Proposition II.6.9 from Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I see that there are already several questions about this Proposition at MSE, I want to add one more.

> Proposition 6.9: Let $X \to Y$ be a finite morphism of non-singular curves, then for any divisor $D$ on $Y$ we have $\deg f^*D=\deg f\deg D$.

Let $Q$ be a closed point in $Y$. Let $\mathrm{Spec}\,B$ be an open affine neighbourhood of $Q$ and $\mathrm{Spec}\,A=f^{-1}(\mathrm{Spec}\,B)$. Denote $A'=S^{-1}A$, where $S=B\backslash\mathfrak m_Q$. Let $\mathfrak m_i$ be a maximal ideal of $A'$. Let $t$ be a local parameter at the point $Q$. Hartshorne uses in the proof that
$$A'/(tA'_{\mathfrak m_i}\cap A')\cong A'_{\mathfrak m_i}/tA'_{\mathfrak m_i}.$$
This would follow from the Second Isomorphism Theorem if $A'_{\mathfrak m_i}=A'+tA'_{\mathfrak m_i}$. To show this it is enough to check that $1/s\in A'+tA'_{\mathfrak m_i}$ for any $s\in A'\backslash \mathfrak m_i$. I tried to show this but it seems that this is wrong if $s\in\mathfrak m_j\backslash\mathfrak m_i$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is: if 
$$t  = {u}^k \cdot \text{ other stuff prime to $u$ },$$ 
then (here $u$ is a uniformizer) localizing at $u$ turns the other stuff into  units:
$$ tA_{(u)}' = u^k A'_{(u)}.$$